# Input data does not contain any rows in Turi Create Model Training

Tags: python

Good day

Recently, I am learning how to train models in Turi Create for iOS CoreML development. I am currently working on gesture image recognition with, in this case, two different datasets, with the code snippet shown below.

```
import turicreate as turi 

    myPath = 'dataset'
    data = turi.image_analysis.load_images(myPath, with_path= True, recursive= True)

    data["gestures"] = data["path"].apply(lambda path: "love" if "love" in path else "metal")

    print(data.groupby("gestures", [turi.aggregate.COUNT]))
    data.save("gestures.sframe")

    #Train Data
    train_data, test_data = data.random_split(0.9)
    model = turi.image_classifier.create(train_data, target="gestures")
    predictions = model.predict(test_data)
    metrics = model.evaluate(test_data)
    print(metrics["accuracy"])

    model.save("gestures.model")
    model.export_coreml("gestures.mlmodel")
```

When I run the code, I encountered by an error stating that

> Exception has occurred: **turicreate.toolkits._main.ToolkitError
>   Input data does not contain any rows.**

That pointed to the code line below

```
predictions = model.predict(test_data)
```

I am a bit confused. Are the any solutions to help me figure out this error?. Much appreciated, thank you

Comment: Are you sure that `test_data` contains elements? Have you tried `print(test_data)` to actually see the data it holds?

Comment: @Ralf I did managed to find the solution by installing Python 2.7+ version in my machine. It works just fine thereafter.